# How to make mutability sensitive Class in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, variables, access-modifiers

I have custom Array-class like:

```
public typealias JsonValue = AnyHashable;

public class Json {
    public private(set) var raw: NSMutableDictionary

// ...

    public subscript(key: String) -> JsonValue? {
        get {
            return self.raw[key];
        }
        set(value) {
            raw[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And later use it like:

```
var myVariable = Json();
myVariable["key"] = "value";
```

But Swift warns like:

```
Variable 'myVariable' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant
```

### How can I tell Swift that I am mutating `myVariable`?

> I already tried `mutating` keyword, but that resulted in error (telling not allowed on setter).
>
> I am using Swift 5 on Xcode 12.

Comment: Why are you using `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift and not `[String: JsonValue]`?

Comment: @Sulthan Using that, multiple references can share same memory and/or array, I don't think it's related to that.

Comment: It's not related to that but using Objective-C types in Swift is always a bad idea. And you don't need `NSMutableDictionary` to share data.

Comment: **Why is this suddenly a duplicate? I am clearly asking for "how to workaround", not why that happens.**

Comment: Just do what it says and change var to let.

Comment: @matt TL;DR; **By changing entire types to `struct` (which were `class`)**, I already solved said question.

Comment: Fair enough, either way would have worked.

Comment: @matt No, not considering what was asked for here, but maybe that works in thread which this was marked as duplicate of.

Comment: That depends on what the problem to be solved is. Your question seems to complain about the warning from Xcode. Changing var to let would have made the warning go away.

Comment: @matt Which complain!? Above asks for behaviour changes. I think "`How to make mutability sensitive Class in Swift?`" is clear enough, but you are free to edit "`How can I tell Swift that I am mutating myVariable?`" part (to whatever helps you understand, that changing from `class` to `struct` is the solution)

Comment: @matt "`Whenever I don't understand something, I read it again and again, till I understand`" (+- from Abu Ali Ibn Sina), in addition to that, "`I press Edit and change, whatever I did not understand on first try`" (from myself ;-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable has a reference (class) type, therefore the variable only holds a *reference* to a class instance, and that was not mutated.

There is a big difference between a `struct` (a value type) and a `class` (a reference type). In this case you should just change the declaration to:

```
let myVariable = Json()
```

To mutate a variable with a reference type, you would have to assign a new instance, e.g.

```
myVariable = Json()
```

> ##### You seem to want value semantics for your `Json` type. If so, just make it a `struct`. For more info, see the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Although indirectly, I am mutating that variable's content, I tried to mark `setter` as `mutating` but Swift gives error. **Swift is wrong in design**, I mean, Swift should either let me pick, or setter should always be mutating. However, any way to workaround that except setting variable multiple times?

Comment: @Top-Master You seem to want value semantics for your `Json` type. If so, just make it a `struct`. For more info, see the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html), which you don't seem to have read at all.

Comment: A `struct` can not inherit any `class`, but for my specific case that was just the right solution, thanks.

Comment: I understand now; in Swift only `struct` is NOT supposed to be mutable,
unless it's defined with `var` and/or `inout` in `func` parameters
(as if changing the **value** is a big thing and should not happen unnoticed),
basically same as `const` keyword available in `C++`,
but in C++ `struct` and `class` themself don't have much difference,
and can inherit each other (which I call good design and thank C++ language).

**However**, in Swift `class` is always mutable, no matter what,
and Swift even warns if we use `var`.

Comment: @Top-Master That's a bit confusing. If you want to compare with C, `let` for classes is the same as a const *pointer*. The difference is that a struct is a value type while a class is a reference type. Assignment to a reference type is what in C++ would be written as `x->a = 1`. The `x` itself does not change because it's a pointer.

Comment: In C++ "`const MyType *myVariable;`" is pretty immutable (raising compile error, on change attempts), and what you try to say with "const pointer" is called "constant-pointer to non-constant" which is rarely used (written like "`MyType * const myVariable;`"), but **unfortunatly Swfit's `class`-types are "pointers to non-constants"**, even warning about `var` keyword (as question shows).

Comment: @Top-Master There's nothing unfortunate about it. The object model in Swift was designed that way. The object model in C++ is overcomplicated and has many problems. Different behavior for value types and reference types is an elegant solution.

Comment: I don't know why you defend Swift; Maybe in future `Swift` versions, they should try to somehow make changes to classes human-readable, but currently yet, if we pass `class` somewhere only god knows what changes happen there, while we expect no changes (BTW, almost every Swift-API is class related, which makes this a big issue).

Comment: Swift's `struct` has "`mutation prevention mechanisms`" like what we know as `class` from other languages, but whatever the intentions behind making Swift's `class` to behave like "`smart-pointer to non-constant`" was, they should at least allow `struct`-type to inherit `class`-type in future Swift-versions (to allow adding "`mutation prevention mechanisms`" later on). - - - Also, in C++ both struct and class are almost equal; maybe you meant other stuff by "overcomplicated" (but those are out of this discussion's scope).

Comment: @Top-Master You are concentrating too much on mutable vs immutable. The principal difference is value-type vs reference-type. This is very similar to the data model in C# which also has structs as value-types. You can also achieve immutability on classes (the same way as in Java - you just make the setters not accessible). The immutability of structs is achieved by the the fact that they are value-types which means their contents are *copied* when you pass them somewhere.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, taking hours to make "for each class a SEPARATE immutable version" is always an option, but compared to C/C++'s `const` keyword both `Swift` and `Java` are far behind (and other languages having same disadvantages as Swift is no excuse, just like other languages being simpler than C/C++ has nothing to do with `const` keyword).

Comment: @Top-Master You should probably use structs and find an alternative to inheritance (e.g. protocols, composition etc.). Inheritance is the least important property of OOP.

Comment: @Sulthan That does not have any time difference to said immutable-version (because we need to write in `struct` custom accessors to private-`class`, right?), but okay friend, as they say "always prefer Composition vs Inheritance" (in other words always prefer Dependency-Injection).